# Python Dictionary Type

Tags: list, python-2.7, types

I'm trying to figure out why I get this type error. Is it possible to put integers inside of dictionaries?

```
math_questions = [
    {'question1':'1*1',
    'answer1':1,
    'quote1' :'What you are,you are by accident of birth; what I am,I am by myself.\n There are and will be a thousand princes; there is only one Beethoven.'},
    {'question2':'2*1',
    'answer2':2,
    'quote2': 'Two is company, three is a crowd'},
    {'question3': '3*1',
    'answer3': 3,
    'quote3': 'There are three types of people, those who can count and those who cannot'}
    ]

# read from a txt file later???

print math_questions[0]['question1']

math_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer to " + math_questions["question1"] +"? : "))

if math_answer == math_questions['answer1']:
    print math_questions['quote']
else:
    print "Try again"
print math_questions['answer1']
```

This is the error message I get.

```
PS C:\python27\math_game> python math_game.py
1*1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "math_game.py", line 17, in <module>
    math_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer to " + math_questions["question1"] +"? : "))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
PS C:\python27\math_game>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a list, you need the **index**. It looks like you are trying to access a `dict`. Instead, put:

```
math_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer to " + math_questions[0]["question1"] +"? : "))
```

You had a few errors:

1. You had `math_questions["question1"]` on line 17, 19, 20, 23
2. You had `math_questions["quote"]` which didn't exist (*I changed to `math_questions["quote1"]`*)

Over here, we try to access a list of `dict`s by the way you used. However, we need to strip it to **just the `dict`** before we access it that way.

```
>>> obj = [{'data1': 68,
... 'data2': 34,
... 'data3': 79}]
>>> obj['data2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>> obj[0]['data2']
34
>>>
```

Here is your updated code:

```
math_questions = [
    {'question1':'1*1',
    'answer1':1,
    'quote1' :'What you are,you are by accident of birth; what I am,I am by myself.\n There are and will be a thousand princes; there is only one Beethoven.'},
    {'question2':'2*1',
    'answer2':2,
    'quote2': 'Two is company, three is a crowd'},
    {'question3': '3*1',
    'answer3': 3,
    'quote3': 'There are three types of people, those who can count and those who cannot'}
    ]

# read from a txt file later???

print math_questions[0]['question1']

math_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer to " + math_questions[0]["question1"] +"? : "))

if math_answer == math_questions[0]['answer1']:
    print math_questions[0]['quote1']
else:
    print "Try again"
print math_questions[0]['answer1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rework your data structure similar to this:

```
class MathQuestion:
  def __init__(self, question, answer, quote):
    self.question = question
    self.answer = answer
    self.quote = quote

math_questions = [
  MathQuestion(question='1*1', answer='1', quote='What you are …'),
  MathQuestion(question='2*1', answer='2', quote='Two is company …'),
  #…
]
```

This allows you to address your strings like this:

```
math_questions[0].answer
```